# C++ Pointer Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I just have a basic question regarding the pointer array.

```
int *Arr[8]; // An array of int pointers

int (*Arr)[8]; // A pointer pointing to an int array
```

If I use the second one, how do I assign integers to the array? I know if were on the heap

```
int *Arr = new int[8]
```

I can just do `Arr[5] = 99`. 
How do I do this on the stake?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: By stake I assume you mean stack?

Comment: @Borgleader Or steak, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this declaration:

```
int (*Arr)[8];
```

you can assign it the address of an `int` array of size 8:

```
int data[8];
Arr = &data;
```

You can modify `data` through `Arr`:

```
(*Arr)[i] = value;
```

Note the parentheses around `*Arr`. They're needed to dereference `Arr` *before* applying the index to it, since the index `[]` operator has a higher precedence.

An important thing to understand here is that `data` is not dynamically allocated. If you keep its address around after it has gone out of scope, you'll get a dangling pointer (a pointer that points to something that no longer exists.)

To dynamically allocate an array and assign it to `Arr`, you can use a typecast on the result of `new` as follows:

```
int (*Arr)[8] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[8]>(new int[8]);
```

(A working example can be found on [ideone](http://ideone.com/VWYxsE).)

Of course it doesn't make much sense to do this in such a roundabout way, as you can instead just:

```
int* Arr = new int[8];
```

And of course you can use an [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector) instead and avoid manual memory management completely:

```
std::vector<int> Arr;
```

Which provides you with an array that grows on its own as needed.

Comment: @NikosC. It is. `*` has a lower precedence than `[]`, doesn't it.

Comment: @H2CO3 I should get in the habbit of compiling code before posting it... :-P You're all right of course, the parens are needed.

Comment: @NikosC. Yup, no worries. It's just so common that it instantly catches my eyes and whenever I see `*arr[idx]`, I always ask "shouldn't this be `(*arr)[idx]` instead?"

Comment: @Nikos.C Thank you very much. is it on the heap, the assign steps int data[8];
Arr = &data; are done by the complier?

Comment: Nikos: add this line I think `Note: [] has higher precedence then * so you have to use ( ) around Arr`--its important point here....I don't have vote to give but you beaten me :).. my vote is pending like..nice answer!

Comment: @user2476381 No, there is no dynamic memory allocated anywhere. These are on the stack. Also, this is code you need to write. Nothing happens automatically here; `int (*Arr)[8];` just declares a pointer that can point to an array, nothing more.

Comment: @NikosC. Sorry, I meant, if were on the heap, int *Arr = new int[8] would do both declaration and assign the integer array for me, is it?

Comment: @NewbieDave, NikosC:  add: `int (*Arr)[8] = (int(*)[8])(new int[8]);` in your answer from my side, if you like.

Comment: @NewbieDave Yes, that is how you create dynamically allocated arrays. I would just use `std::vector` though; there's no need to mess with manual memory allocation (unless you're doing it for learning purposes.)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'd use `reinterpret_cast` instead. Note that you can just edit the answer yourself and add it. :-)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Shouldn't it be `int (*Arr)[8] = (int(*)[8])(new int*[8]);` - or do you want to use array of eight ints as array of eight pointers to int?

Comment: @NikosC. Oh NikosC it just our first meet so didn't edit without your permission :)  just adding wait

Comment: @j_kubik `new int*[8]` means array of pointers we need array of int, and `sizeof(int)` may not = `sizeof(void*)`

Comment: NikosC. check for English I added.   @j_kubik check answer I given a link of ideone.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks. Corrected grammar and used `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @NewbieDave, Nikos: Hm, Now answer is very helpful. additional information I can add in comment, if you one wants to initialized a pointer of array statically he can do: `int (*Arr)[5] = (int [][5]){ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } , { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };` ..its quite similar to `int* arr = (int[5]){ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }` that is similar to `char* str = "hello";`, because OP wanted to allcate dynamically someone may like statically-assign value.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using C++, is there any reason why a container such as `std::array` would not be applicable? For example:

```
std::array<int, 8> arr;
std::array<int, 8>* arr_p = &arr;
```

and if you didn't know the size until run-time, you could use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(8);
```

The code that you have is correct, but given that the standard libraries are available, most would probably recommend using the containers and algorithms as opposed to manually managing memory yourself which is prone to bugs and memory leaks, especially when exceptions are involved.